# React-bootstrap Nav activeKey doesn't change the NavItem's status to active

Tags: react-bootstrap

```
<Nav pullRight activeKey={1}>
   <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#" active>技术秘籍</NavItem>
   <NavItem eventKey={2}>生活点滴</NavItem>
   <NavItem eventKey={3} href="#">休闲娱乐</NavItem>
   <NavItem eventKey={4} href="#">沟通交流</NavItem>
   <NavItem eventKey={5} href="#">关于博主</NavItem>
</Nav>
```

I want the first item to be active when it's initial, but the active did not do anything, is anyone know why

Comment: Did you ever figure out this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding your activeKey value by also specifying "active" on your first NavItem.

Effectively setting "activeKey={1}" is achieving what you are asking for. However, this also means that you are hardwiring your prop to 1, so it will never change.

Probably what you really want is something including local state, i.e.:

```
const Navigation = React.createClass({
getInitialState() {
  return {activeKey: 1};
},

handleSelect(selectedKey) {
  this.setState({activeKey: selectedKey});
},

render() {

  return (
  <Navbar fixedTop>
    <Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Brand>
        <a className="page-scroll" href="#page-top" onClick={this.handleSelect.bind(null, 0)}>Some Brand</a>
      </Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle />
    </Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Collapse>
      <Nav bsStyle="pills" activeKey={this.state.activeKey} onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
        <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link</NavItem>
        <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link</NavItem>
        <NavItem eventKey={3} href="#">Link</NavItem>
        <NavItem eventKey={4} href="#">Link</NavItem>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Navbar>
);
}
});
```

I put the navbrand also in there, to show how to .bind the click handler with a specific value (i.e. 0 means neutral - no highlighting).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i try to add active to the NavItem did not have any change , howerver, when i add disabled to the NavItem it changed

Answer (score 0):

first, import useLocation from react-router-dom
inside your class, but before your return or render statement, set a variable equal to **useLocation()** (I just name it **location** in my code)

inside your nav menu links, you want to add eventKey="*your relative path here*"
on the nav declaration, add **activeKey={location.pathname}**

this works for navdropdown as well.  I am using react-bootstrap components (NavBar, Nav, Nav.Link, NavDropDown)